# INSERT INTO ... VALUES + implode();

Tags: php, sql

Скажите, можно ли при написании запроса в VALUES воспользоваться одной функцией impload, чтобы занести все значения из массива, и как?

```
if (count($our_extremist_materials) > 0) {
  $kernel->execute('INSERT INTO block_content (id) VALUES ('.implode('),(',$our_extremist_materials).')');
}
```

Эта реализация не работает.

Comment: 1) `echo 'INSERT INTO block_content (id) VALUES ('.implode('),(',$our_extremist_materials).')';` 2) выполните получившееся в ручном режиме и посмотрите что напишет mysql

Comment: Ох, а ведь работает!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно можно , но данные лучше заливать через prepare , у вас я так понимаю PDO тогда вот такой пример:

```
//массив с названием полей и их значениями
$array = ['field_a' => 'a' , 'field_b' => 'b'];
//берем название полей для указания куда вставлять данные
$fields = array_keys($array);
//1 implode формирует строку с названиями , 
//2 формирует строку с названиями полей массива от куда брять данные
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO 
        saleData( " . implode(",", $fields) . " ) 
        VALUES ( :" . implode(",:", $fields) . " )";
```

Тот же пример но без prepare , тоесть берем название полей и их значения

```
//массив с названием полей и их значениями
$array = ['field_a' => 'a' , 'field_b' => 'b'];
//берем название полей для указания куда вставлять данные
$fields = array_keys($array);
//берем значения 
$values = array_values($array);
//1 implode формирует строку с названиями (field_a , field_b), 
//2 формирует строку с значениями ('a', 'b')
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO 
        table_a( " . implode(",", $fields) . " ) 
        VALUES ( '" . implode("','", $values) . "' )";
```

Можно еще вот так , динамическая простоновка обновляемых полей при дублях , тут используем `array_reduce` - уменьшает массив к единственному значению , формируем строку вида `field_a = VALUES(field_a) , field_b = VALUES(field_b)`

```
 $updateFields = ['field_a' => 'a' , 'field_b' => 'b'];
 $sql = "INSERT INTO table_a
         SELECT * FROM table_b
         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " .
         array_reduce($updateFields, function($carry, $key){
             return ($carry ? $carry . "," : "") . $key . " = VALUES($key) ";
         });
```

Comment: А можете подробнее расписать про каждый пример? Будет ли это работать не в PDO?

Comment: Да пожалуйста , обновил свой пост . По поводу работы вне `PDO` => конечно будет , `SQL` он же везде `SQL`